# Reference to a external Panel (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint, border-layout

I have an application that has a `BorderLayout`. In the Center of this layout I have a `JPanel` that is called mainContent.

Now I have a method like this:

```
public void setMainPanel(JPanel panel){
    mainPanel = panel;
    gui.repaint();
    gui.revalidate();
}
```

Here I can set the reference from the `mainPanel` to a new panel, but it's not possible to make it visible! So I have no idea how I can refresh the GUI!

I tried `repaint` and `revalidate`! The variable GUI is the `JFrame`! The `setMainPanel` method is defined in the frame Class.

How can I refresh/repaint the content?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score 3):

This line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
mainPanel = panel;
```

This just updates the reference of `mainPanel` variable to point to `panel`, but it won't update the container with `BorderLayout`, because this container will keep a reference to the previous panel.

Assuming `gui` is the container with `BorderLayout`, you should do as follows:

```
public void setMainPanel(JPanel panel){
    gui.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    gui.revalidate();
    gui.repaint();
}
```

#### Off-topic

Please take a look to this topic: [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)